# want to add multiples tables to a frame dynamically

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I want to add a number of tables to my frame , depending on the out come of something

so put this

```
        int x=17;
    int y=95;
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
    table[i].setBounds(x+50,y+50, 525, 44);
    contentPane.add(table[i]);
    }
```

but nothing happing

Comment: you need a new instance of table every time you add it to contentPane for a start

Answer (score 2):

You're ignoring the Java layout managers completely, first by trying to add multiple components to the content pane, without realizing that it's default BorderLayout will mean that any component added later will cover and replace all components added previously, and next by trying to use `setBounds` a newbie crutch. Solution: use the layout managers to their full benefit. For example if you set the contentPane to use a GridLayout or a BoxLayout, and then add JTables (wrapped in JScrollPanes) to it, you'll likely get much closer to what you want.

You could use a `null` layout, but I'm going to strenuously recommend that you don't. While null layouts and `setBounds()` might seem to Swing newbies like the easiest and best way to create complex GUI's, the more Swing GUI'S you create the more serious difficulties you will run into when using them. They won't resize your components when the GUI resizes, they are a royal witch to enhance or maintain, they fail completely when placed in scrollpanes, they look gawd-awful when viewed on all platforms or screen resolutions that are different from the original one.

Most important -- Google and study the Java Swing tutorials, especially the layout manager section.

Comment: can you give me more details pleas or even edit my code

Comment: @AyoubBelkas: You need to learn how to use layout managers and basic rudiments of Swing, and we can't give that to you, but fortunately the tutorials can help, and you can find links to the Swing tutorials and to other Swing resources here: [Swing Info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/swing/info). As for your code, frankly don't bother editing it, delete it and start over.